# Error associated with parameters in Minimize (or NMinimize) in discrete fitting

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

my problem goes as follows:

I need to a discrete fit of a discrete function. Say I have the following made up data points, which are generated by the parabola `f[x_]:=x^2` with some "experimental error" added:

```
data := {{-3, 8.9}, {-2, 4.1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1.2}, {2, 3.9}, {3,9.2}};
valuex := {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}
valuey := {8.9, 4.1, 1, 0, 1.2, 3.9, 9.2}
```

These points should be fitted by a curve of the general formula `f[x_]:= a*x² +
 b*x + c`, and I built a `NMinimize` algorithm as:

```
Minimize[Sqrt[Plus @@ ((a*valuex^2 + b*valuex + c - valuey )^2)], {a, b, c}]
```

This gives off a pretty accurate value for a, b and c

```
{0.282, {a -> 0.99881, b -> 0.025, c -> 0.0476191}}
```

these are basically the same values I got when using `NonlinearModelFit`

```
nmf = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x^2 + b x + c, {a, b, c}, x]
FittedModel[0.047619+0.025x+0.99881x^2
```

Now what `nmf` gives me, that I need to calculate in the `NMinimize` case is the `nmf["ParameterErrors"]`, `{0.0153843, 0.0266465, 0.0814063}`.

How can I do that manually? I tried looking it up how `NonlinearModelFit` does it, but my lack of mathematical knowledge is making things pretty hard.

Any help regarding that matter is welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

p.s.: I don't know if I made it clear enough, but that is just an example function. The one I need to fit is much more complicated and cannot be analytically evaluated, making `NMinimize` essential.

Comment: My post used to begin with "Hello all, " but somehow that got deleted. I tried editing to add it again and nothing. Are headers like that automatically excluded? Anyway, just letting you know what was the edit about.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @LeFerret Yes, generally posts are to be statements of questions, with whatever background etc is necessary.  Not in "letter" format (no salutations, no closings).  I didn't realize the SE bot catches some of that stuff.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72047/when-fitting-a-curve-how-do-i-calculate-the-95-confidence-interval-for-my-fitt

Comment: @Lou: Thank you for the calrification.